Distinct values based on boolean measure
I have a table like
Point of sales  Employee    Category    Answer  Supervisor  Date
POS35   Emp6    Wine    2   SV3 07.05.2024
POS70   Emp13   Cognac  1   SV1 17.05.2024
POS237  Emp1    Wine    1   SV1 31.05.2024
POS171  Emp9    Wine    1   SV1 17.05.2024
POS20   Emp20   Cognac  0   SV1 09.05.2024
POS160  Emp20   Wine    2   SV1 31.05.2024
POS117  Emp13   Wine    0   SV1 20.05.2024
POS241  Emp3    Cognac  0   SV1 01.05.2024
POS163  Emp6    Cognac  0   SV3 20.05.2024
POS41   Emp12   Cognac  1   SV3 05.05.2024
POS138  Emp17   Cognac  1   SV1 16.05.2024
enter image description here
In Power Pivot I creatted three measures:

returns True if POS has at least one "1" answer
returns True if POS has zero "1" answers and at least one "2"
returns True if POS has only "0" answers

How to create a measure to calculate how many POS correspond with each condition (measure)
I tried next formula, but it doesn't work:
Meet cond1:=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('TableName'[Point of sales]);
FILTER('TableName';[measure1]=TRUE()))

Please [edit] your question to format the data. You can get help on creating tables by clicking the ? button on the right side of the editor toolbar.

maybe you can try this
Measure 1:=COUNTX(FILTER(Table1,[Answer]>=1),[Point of sales])

Measure 3:=COUNTX(FILTER(Table1,[Answer]=0),[Point of sales])

what about the second one? not very clear about your request. could you please provide the expected output that based on the sample data you provided?
